# 'ERESOLVE' error with npm, specifically related to the conflicting dependencies of 'react-loader-spinner' and 'react' in the react project?

Tags: reactjs, json, npm

I was following a youTube tutorial to make a project but After adding some dependencies and running `npm install` this error is show -:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: gym_exercises@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from react-loader-spinner@6.0.0-0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-loader-spinner
npm ERR!   react-loader-spinner@"^6.0.0-0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My package.json file is -:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^2.7.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^6.0.0-0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am new to react can somebody please help me to resolve this error.
I have given my pacakage.json file above, if anyone require any other file please let me know.

Comment: Did you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner?activeTab=versions package, there is no `6.0.0` version, try to install `5.3.4`
`